# Find fourth Thursday each month and if NASDAQ closed that day, take next day

Tags: excel, datetime, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am working in Excel where I need to find the fourth Thursday in each month but if on that day NASDAQ is closed take the day after. I have this formula for each fourth Thursday:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1)),26,25,24,23,22,28,27))
```

but I am not be to get the next business day where the fourth Thursday is any one of:

```
01-Jan-14
20-Jan-14
17-Feb-14
18-Apr-14
26-May-14
03-Jul-14
04-Jul-14
01-Sep-14
27-Nov-14
28-Nov-14
24-Dec-14
25-Dec-14
```

Comment: it'd make for an ugly formula, but couldn't you wrap it in an IF statement, and if it's blank (or an error) calculate the next business day?

Comment: That's what I was thinking sous2817

Comment: i was trying that. it didnt get the required result..

Comment: If 4th Thursday is a trading holiday then it is not present. for ex.  22-Dec-14
23-Dec-14
29-Dec-14
30-Dec-14
31-Dec-14

Comment: Can you post the series?

Comment: this year, the 4th Thursday in December is the 24th, right?  Wouldn't that be a holiday as well?

Comment: my date series is from 01-Jan-2014 to 31-Dec-2014 excluding all holidays days of NASDAQ and weekends

Comment: NASDAQ Holiday list
01-Jan-14
20-Jan-14
17-Feb-14
18-Apr-14
26-May-14
03-Jul-14
04-Jul-14
01-Sep-14
27-Nov-14
28-Nov-14
24-Dec-14
25-Dec-14

Comment: thank you so much everyone, I got a solution with lots of IF

Answer (score 0):

Please try appending to your formula:

```
+IF(OR(A2=41823,A2=41970,A2=41998),1,0)
```